# Mono.Cecil: Insert a log statement in method's beginning

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

I am using Mono.Cecil to edit my target method's IL code so that I can log that method's entry point, without editing the actual code.
I am able to insert a call instruction to a method which can perform logging operation.
But I don't know how to log my target method's input parameters.
In short i want to insert an instruction in the target method by changing it's IL code to do a log or say print operation to log the input parameter values passed to that method.

I tried a basic program as sample.

```
public class Target
{
    // My target method. 
    public void Run(int arg0, string arg1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Run method body");
    }


}

public static class Trace{

// This is my log method, which i want to call in begining of Run() method. 
    public void LogEntry(string methodName, object[] params)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("******Entered in "+ methodName+" method.***********")
    // With params :......
    //
    }
}
```

Source program.

```
public class Sample 
{
    private readonly string _targetFileName;
    private readonly ModuleDefinition _module;

    public ModuleDefinition TargetModule { get { return _module; } }

    public Sample(string targetFileName)
    {
        _targetFileName = targetFileName;

        // Read the module with default parameters
        _module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(_targetFileName);
    }

    public void Run(string type, string method)
    {

        // Retrive the target class. 
        var targetType = _module.Types.Single(t => t.Name == type);

        // Retrieve the target method.
        var runMethod = targetType.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == method);

        // Get a ILProcessor for the Run method
        var processor = runMethod.Body.GetILProcessor();

        // get log entry method ref to create instruction
        var logEntryMethodReference = targetType.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "LogEntry");

   // Import ..
    //
        var newInstruction = processor.Create(OpCodes.Call, logEntryMethodReference);

        var firstInstruction = runMethod.Body.Instructions[0];

        processor.InsertBefore(firstInstruction, newInstruction);

        // Write the module with default parameters
        _module.Write(_targetFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, but without some sample code, I don't think any of us can do anything to help :) Please post what you have so far (and not to be pompous, but this is usually true for every question you'll have from now on; some other, less understanding people might give you negative votes even if you miss the source code for question like these).

Comment: @Akos I have updated.

Comment: Are you sure this is OK? I guess here the `targetType` is `Target`, but the `LogEntry` method is in the `Trace` class (note that both the class and the method must be static). When you do `targetType.Methods.Single()` and look for `LogEntry`, that looks for the method in `Target`, not in `Trace`. Or Am I missing something?

Comment: @AkosNagy yes you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this was interesting :)
Here's my working sample (comments in the code, feel free to ask anything, if not clear):

Modified sample (to actually write out the parameters):

```
public class Target
{
    // My target method. 
    public void Run(int arg0, string arg1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Run method body");
    }

}

public static class Trace
{

    // This is my log method, which i want to call in begining of Run() method. 
    public static void LogEntry(string methodName, object[] parameters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("******Entered in " + methodName + " method.***********");
        Console.WriteLine(parameters[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(parameters[1]);
    }
}
```

Source program to handle IL injection:

```
public class Sample
{
    private readonly string _targetFileName;
    private readonly ModuleDefinition _module;

    public ModuleDefinition TargetModule { get { return _module; } }

    public Sample(string targetFileName)
    {
        _targetFileName = targetFileName;

        // Read the module with default parameters
        _module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(_targetFileName);
    }

    public void Run(string type, string method)
    {

        // Retrive the target class. 
        var targetType = _module.Types.Single(t => t.Name == type);

        // Retrieve the target method.
        var runMethod = targetType.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == method);

        // Get a ILProcessor for the Run method


        // get log entry method ref to create instruction
        var logEntryMethodReference = _module.Types.Single(t => t.Name == "Trace").Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "LogEntry");


        List<Instruction> newInstructions = new List<Instruction>();


        var arrayDef = new VariableDefinition(new ArrayType(_module.TypeSystem.Object)); // create variable to hold the array to be passed to the LogEntry() method            
        runMethod.Body.Variables.Add(arrayDef);  // add variable to the method          

        var processor = runMethod.Body.GetILProcessor();

        newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, runMethod.Parameters.Count));  // load to the stack the number of parameters                      
        newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Newarr, _module.TypeSystem.Object)); // create a new object[] with the number loaded to the stack           
        newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Stloc, arrayDef)); // store the array in the local variable

        // loop through the parameters of the method to run
        for (int i = 0; i < runMethod.Parameters.Count; i++)
        {
            newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc, arrayDef)); // load the array from the local variable
            newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i)); // load the index
            newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg, i+1)); // load the argument of the original method (note that parameter 0 is 'this', that's omitted)

            if (runMethod.Parameters[i].ParameterType.IsValueType)
            {
                newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Box, runMethod.Parameters[i].ParameterType)); // boxing is needed for value types
            }
            else
            { 
                newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Castclass, _module.TypeSystem.Object)); // casting for reference types
            }
            newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref)); // store in the array
        }

        newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, method)); // load the method name to the stack
        newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc, arrayDef)); // load the array to the stack
        newInstructions.Add(processor.Create(OpCodes.Call, logEntryMethodReference)); // call the LogEntry() method


        foreach (var newInstruction in newInstructions.Reverse<Instruction>()) // add the new instructions in referse order
        {
            var firstInstruction = runMethod.Body.Instructions[0];
            processor.InsertBefore(firstInstruction, newInstruction);
        }

        // Write the module with default parameters
        _module.Write(_targetFileName);
    }
}
```